# SharePoint 2013 search server Prerequisite actions before increase in CPU cores and RAM size

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search

we are planning for increasing the CPU cores and RAM size for our SharePoint 2013 dedicated search servers as these servers are consuming High CPU usage and memory utilization with increase in the number of indexed items

What are the prerequisite actions should SharePoint Admin take before the infra team can proceed on this hardware upgrade.

We believe suspend and resume search application using Powers Shell are enough or do we need to take any other backup things?

Answer (score 0):

pause(suspending) the search service application may be enough in most cases.

But as you are upgrading the hardware on all servers which will bring the Servers down and you have Sharepoint on these servers. I would highly recommend to shutdown the SharePoint on the servers then upgrade the hardware. Once completed then bring the sharepoint back online.

Comment: Hi Waqas, you are suggesting shutting down sharepoint on search servers. Do you mean to stop the relevant SharePoint services like SPSearch Service, SP Timerservice, SP Admin Service, Worldwide publishing service etc in the services.msc console in search servers. Please clarify.

Comment: Correct that what I mean